# Android Usage Events: APP_RESUMED twice

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-activitymanager

I am using the `UsageEvents` API to calculate daily foreground time of installed apps on an Android device

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageEvents.Event

What I am doing is ordering the events by time for each activity and computing the time in between `RESUME` and `PAUSED` events

[image]

in some cases I see two consecutive `RESUMED` events. What does it mean? How is it possible that an app is resumed if it's already in foreground?